# Change page if reloaded

Tags: php, forms, reload

In a page I've to fill a form and then submit it to a page of success ("success.php")
In that page, all the information of the form is inserted in the database

How can I change the page (as redirecting to another one) when reloading?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Maybe add some logic like this to your `success.php` script:

```
    <?php
    $formdata_already_saved = //verify if results in database - returning true or false

    if ($formdata_already_saved == true)
    {
        header('location:path to desired location');
        //make sure header is very first output to browser
    }
    else
    {
    //save form data to database...
    }
    ?>
```